# Define an include path in VisualStudio based on build-configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I use the [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) library with VisualStudio and it needs to include a `setup.h` that matches the actual build configuration:

- `lib\vc142_dll\mswu\wx\setup.h` when in **Release** mode
- `lib\vc142_dll\mswud\wx\setup.h` when in **Debug** mode

I already know I can substitute `142` with `$(PlatformToolsetVersion)`. So my question is:

Is there a similar variable for the release/debug mode? I.e. a variable that is *"d"* in Debug-mode and empty otherwise? So I could just put

`lib\vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion)_dll\mswu$(DifDebugMode)\wx\setup.h`

in all configurations.

I use the binary distribution (the packages *header files* and *development files*), not the source distribution that comes with a `*.props` file.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRhoZcNpMb4&t=102s

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the link! Unfortunately I use the binary distribution, not the source distribution, so I do not have access to the mentioned `*.props` file. I edited my question to mention that.